# How can I create a test account?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts

I tried to create a Stack Overflow account for testing, so I can temporarily step into the shoes of a new user. During registration I entered my OpenID email, so when I log in, I get my main account.

Given the fact that I only have one permanent email account, is there a way to sign up for a new Stack Overflow account? Do I need to create a temporary email account?

Comment: What OpenID provider are you using?

Comment: @YannisRizos My Google account.

Comment: I guess you could even do it by using GMail's allowance for `+something` in your email address? So if you use mymail@gmail.com, you could simply use mymail+testso@gmail.com without having to create a new account. (Or am I talking nonsense here?)

Comment: @Bart What? Gmail does that?

Comment: Yep, don't know what it's called, but that's how I filter some content.

Comment: @Bart That's how I registered my [Smelly Sock](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/61598/smelly-sock).

Comment: I noticed the resemblance. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using Gmail and assuming your email is `username@gmail.com`, you can use `username+whatever@gmail.com` for the test account. Gmail ignores everything after the plus sign, and will redirect all emails send there to your regular account. After you register you will be asked if you want to associate the two accounts, the registration process is smart enough to link `username@gmail.com` to `username+whatever@gmail.com`, but you can simply say no.

It would be nice if you add a link to your test account in your main's account about box, and vice versa, so we know that it's a legit test account. Do *not* use the test account to vote on your main account's posts, this would be vote fraud, you'll be caught and punished severely (I've heard rumours there's spanking involved).

Comment: The rumors about spanking are wildly exaggerated. The ones about the tazing, not so much

Comment: ...but: does that also create multiple Google OpenID accounts? (Of course, one could use a Gmail email alias to create a non-Google OpenID account, but that's not what you're saying?)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a not registered account: Browse on Stack Overflow using a browser you have never used to log in on Stack Overflow, and you can create a not registered account.

This works if you are going to ask a question, or answering a question. If you don't plan to do that, then [Yannis Rizos's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143318/167443) is what you can do.