# Deleting the user and creating new users in the same browser

Tags: support, user-accounts

Why can't I in Stack Overflow, delete the user which I have created and also can't create a new user account in the same browser?

If I try to do it by logging out from my account and signing up, it again gets into the account instead of going to the signup page.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a question ban?  If so, this is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: User accounts don't *expire*, so I can't imagine what the point of this would be. Why should we optimize the UI to do something that is extremely rare?

Comment: @CodyGray I doubt it's "rare". I bet hundreds or thousands of people try to get around a Q-ban by deleting their account like this.

Comment: this should be tagged "status-bydesign"?

Comment: I urge you not to do what you are trying to do here. It will cause you pain. I suggest paying attention to the message you are getting when trying to post. [Please read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really remove your user profile, you should contact [Stack Exchange Community Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Multiaccounts on Stack Overflow (and every Stack Exchange sites) are **NOT** permitted in almost every case, don't try to betray question ban or other blockade (of course, if you have it).

If you are register in Stack Exchange OpenID, [log out here](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user), and then you will be able to register, but remember - if you want to have multiaccount - that is illegal.

Comment: Quick note: you mention in your second sentence that multiaccounts are permitted, but in the third sentence, you infer that they are illegal.

Comment: My inconsistency, sorry

Comment: Multi-accounts are actually not explicitly prohibited. However, using them to avoid a ban or a suspension, or to vote cheat is prohibited.

Comment: In a general sense, you can say that we allow accounts created _in good faith_. If you're creating an account to do something you can't do with your existing account, then you're creating it in _bad_ faith, and it's very likely to be removed.

Comment: So basically, you can create an account for [testing purposes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143317/how-can-i-create-a-test-account?rq=1) as an example of a valid use case

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, i think this is no big deal to discuss it this serious because my intention is not to 'betray/disguise/hide the ban'- because i'm not behind the votes i get for the questions. I just need answers only for which i post something. All i'm going to have for me is the answer and not the votes. (Of course votes are needed but i mean to say that they are not of primary concern but answers are).

Consider the case wherein an user is imposed a Q-ban. He has an urgent need for getting answer to something which can't be done at that time. Instead he creates a new account which you claim to be illegal. Also he is not going to use the former account anymore which could occupy some dump space somewhere (This is my first concern for deleting user accounts. Why to have accounts that are no longer gonna be used?).

I hope there is nothing offensive in the aforesaid statement. Just shared my thoughts. Expecting comments. Thanks.

Comment: The point of a question ban is to keep people from posting *more* crappy questions. Creating a new account to get around that question ban defeats the point. We end up with *more crappy questions*.

Comment: Who knows, the next one may be a good one. In that case?

Comment: It is statistically unlikely. With a confidence interval exceeding the site's uptime. We do not care about people's urgent needs, we care about the overall quality of questions on the site.